# python UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison. How to solve this error?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309954/how-do-i-solve-the-unicodewarning-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756205/unicodewarning-unicode-equal-comparison-failed-to-convert-both-arguments-to-uni), i run this code:

```
with open(fin,'r') as inFile, open(fout,'w') as outFile:
  for line in inFile:
     line = line.replace('."</documents', '"').replace('. ', ' ')
     print(' '.join([word for word in line.lower().split() if len(word) >=3 and word not in stopwords.words('english')]), file = outFile)
```

and i have the following error:

```
**UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  print(' '.join([word for word in line.lower().split() if len(word) >=3 and word not in stopwords.words('english')]), file = outFile)**
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`word not in stopwords.words('english')` uses comparisons. Either `word` or at least one of the values in `stopwords.words('english')` is not a Unicode value.

Since you are reading from a file, the most likely candidate here is `word`; decode it, or use a file object that decodes data as it is being read:

```
print(' '.join([word for word in line.lower().split()
                if len(word) >=3 and
                   word.decode('utf8') not in stopwords.words('english')]),
      file = outFile)**
```

or

```
import io

with io.open(fin,'r', encoding='utf8') as inFile,\
        io.open(fout,'w', encoding='utf8') as outFile:
```

where the [`io.open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) gives you a file object in text mode that encodes or decodes as required.

The latter is less error-prone. For example, you test the length of `word`, but what you are really testing there is the *number of bytes*. Any word containing characters outside of the ASCII codepoint range will result in more than one UTF-8 byte per character, so `len(word)` is not the same thing as `len(word.decode('utf8'))`.

Comment: thank you @martijn-pieters, `word.decode('utf8')` works well!

Comment: what is more efficient? using io or the first method ?

Comment: @user275832: I'd use the second method; deal directly with Unicode values, not with the UTF-8 bytes.